# If, else if, else

Tags: java

Let's say that I have two strings that can be passed as parameter:

```
String one = "one";
String two = "two";
```

Which of the following methods would be the most efficiënt?

```
private void exampleOne(String example){
     if(example.equals("one"){
         // do this
     }else{
         // do this
     }
}

private void exampleTwo(String example){
     if(example.equals("one"){
         //do this
     }else if(example.equals("two"){
         // do this
     }
}


private void exampleThree(String example){
     if(example.equals("one"){
         // do this
     }
     if(example.equals("two"){
         // do this
     }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you try adding System.currentTimeInMillis() at start and end of each method and call it for one million times? :P

Comment: Else if will almost always be more efficient.  Once you get a match, you fall through the rest.  But each IF will process, no matter what.

Comment: The given implementations are different in terms of result, so it's not a matter of being efficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would compare the methods for efficiency, if they have the same functionality. Currently, all the 3 methods are functionally different. So, no point is there in comparing them.

1. `exampleOne()` - If example is equal to `"one"`, execute `if`. Execute `else` for all other values.
2. `exampleTwo()` - If example is equal to `"one"`, execute `if`. Execute `else if`, if it is equal to `"two"`, else for all other values, do *nothing* - (Here's one difference).
3. `exampleThree()` - Well, this one (as it stands) is more or less same as the 1st one, with one extra comparison, which btw, isn't going to affect much as far as efficiency is concerned. However, there are chances that both the `if` statements might execute in this method, if in between the two `if` statements, you assign string `"two"` to `example`, which is not possible in `exampleOne` method. To be more clear, you have two independent `if` blocks here, while in the first method, it's an `if-else` block (only one of which will be executed).

Comment: I do not agree with point 3. Is not the same it may look like but it not. In the 1 you have two logical paths, in the 3 you have four of them.

Comment: @Vash That is why I said *more or less same* and not *exactly same*. I've explained the difference in the last statement of point 3.

Answer (score 3):

The one that, statistically speaking, makes the fewest string compares i.e.

```
if (example.equals("one"){
    // do this
} else {
    // do this
}
```

Comment: That code sample is not the same as the others, there is no possible answer here.

Comment: No the code is different but the specification states two possible strings.

Answer (score 2):

No one is the most efficient due that you have just two options, you should consider that the value doesn't be not one and not two, maybe other one (empty? null?) SO you should write something like that:

```
 if(example.equals("one"){
     //do this 1
 }else if(example.equals("two"){
     // do this 2
 }else{
    // do this 3
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Those blocs can not be compared ans you can not state what is the best of them as they flow is different for each case.

This bloc provide two paths a positive and not.

```
private void exampleOne(String example){
     if("one".equals(example){ //deciosn
         // path positive
     }else{
         // path negative 
     }
}
```

This block provide three paths, positive, negative-positive, negative-negative

```
private void exampleTwo(String example){
     if("one".equals(example){
         //path positive
     }else {
        // path negative 
        if("two".equals(example{
         // path negative-positive 
        }
     }
}
```

This block provide four path, postive, negative and positive negative.

```
private void exampleThree(String example){
     if("pne".equals(example){ 
         // path positive
     }
     if("two".equals(example){
         // path positive
     }
}
```

As you see you have four different piece of code that you should not compare to state what is more efficient.

You should focus on the algorithm behind instead not how do the look.

Tip:

Try to use constant on the left side of compare, so you would avoid problems like dereferences and invalid assign.

Answer (score 1):

The **first** one. Because you don't have to check other condition. In other you to make more operation.

The most efficient: 1, 2, 3.

But If you will have to check if `i==0` and you will expect that most of them will be `!=` better write `if (i != 0) {} else{}` than `If (i==0) {...}`

Keep everything as simple as possible

Answer (score 1):

I would say the first one, just because it only has to evaluate one expression every time...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the **second one** because there you have direct control on both scenarios. When Sring is "one" and "two".

In exampleOne, the method doens't care if "two" or "three" is passed. It cares only situation if "one" is passed

Answer (score 0):

I'd say first, because if it just says else with no condition then it won't have to check anything, just go straight into 'else'

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, the first is most efficient. 
Practically, you should go for the second, as it offers better readability and maintainability.

Remember, premature optimization is the root of all evil :)

Answer (score 0):

1) most efficient, but this isn't good for maintainability.

```
private void exampleOne(String example){
     if(example.equals("one"){
         // do this
     }else{
         // do this
     }
}
```

2) second efficient, but it is good for maintainability.

```
private void exampleTwo(String example){
     if(example.equals("one"){
         //do this
     }else if(example.equals("two"){
         // do this
     }
}
```

3) third efficient.

```
private void exampleThree(String example){
     if(example.equals("one"){
         // do this
     }
     if(example.equals("two"){
         // do this
     }
}
```

Comment: Why should b) be more efficient than c)? In assembler, 2) would need one more jump than 3), if I remember my assembler days correctly...

Comment: 3) if example is "one", two String#equals is invoked while 2) one invoked.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what are your needs so, here you have mi opinions,

the first one, will ALLWAYS do only one checking.. so in that particular example it will be the one with less COMPARISONS.

the second ONE, will do at worst 2 comparisons 1 for "one" and 1 for "two" but... (there is allways a but) it will not any any job if the string is lets say "three" (in the first example it will go to the else)

the 3 example will do ALWAYS 2 COMPARISONS un less you put returns inside the ifs.

so, my opinion is there is not enough information to say wich one is more optimal.

one adition: you can try, instead of writing endles if... to use a case like this one:

```
switch (true) {
        case example.equals("one"):  
                 break;
        case example.equals("two"):  
                 break;

        default: 
                 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the first method would be the most efficient one compared with the possible values of parameters , since the additional if condition in the other methods is useless and will have nothing to do in your case. (extra condition check ==> lower efficiency)